# How to exclude files from merging?

Tags: git, merge

Just started to get my head around git and at the moment looking at merging. Suppose I have a master branch and I create a branch called child of this. I work on the childbranch and change some files. Now I want to merge this childbranch into the master branch:

```
git merge child
```

There are some files in the child branch however(that are also in the masterbranch) that I dont want to merge however. How can I merge my changes from the child into the master but exclude specific files from the child?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is simple: no.

The long answer is much more complicated, but also amounts to "no".  Essentially, you can, in *some* circumstances, make Git believe that if there are changes on *both sides* of a merge, the changes *always conflict*.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38023172/1256452) to a related question (although all I really say is that you can mark files as binary, or set up special merge drivers, but there's a lot of background you need to understand even to get to this point).

What you can do, if you want to avoid certain files, is to run your `git merge` with `--no-commit`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git checkout -b sidebranch
... lots of coding, git committing, etc
$ git checkout master
... more coding and committing, etc.,
    or various merges of other branches,
    so that master and sidebranch are
    actually divergent (if they are
    not, note that merge would
    normally do a "fast forward" here)
$ git merge --no-commit sidebranch
```

At this point, Git will do the merge using the process I describe in the linked answer (by doing two diffs, then combining the two diffs).  But it won't auto-commit the resulting merge, *even if it succeeds*.

This means you can now do this:

```
$ git rm path/to/ickyfile
    # we don't want this file, it's icky!
```

and/or this:

```
$ git checkout --ours -- path/to/foo; git add path/to/foo
    # we want the current (master) version of this file,
    # ignoring all the changes made in the side branch
```

and even stuff like this (but don't: the result is sometimes called an "evil merge"):

```
$ vim path/to/bar
<make changes that come from neither master nor sidebranch>
$ git add path/to/bar
```

Once you're all done making bad things happen to a good merge :-) you can then run `git commit` to complete the merge.

**In general, if you find that you need to do this, you are probably using the wrong tools.**  In particular, people often do the above with configuration files, when the "right" thing is *not to put those files in Git (or any version control system) in the first place.*

(Instead, put an *example* configuration file in the VCS.  Instead of `prog.conf`, add and commit `prog.conf.example`.  Put `prog.conf` in your `.gitignore`.  Your install / initialization code can copy the example config into place if needed, for new user setup.)

Answer (score 3):

If the reason you are hesitant to merge is that you will encounter merge conflicts, I think you shouldn't be. 
Merge conflict resolution, although a difficult task to learn, is something that you can benefit from immensely.

However, if you'd rather not do that now, or if your problem is something else, I can think of a few ways to exclude the files from the childbranch:

**Method 1.** If the changes to the files are in their own commits, then you can create patches out of those commits, and 'drop' those commits from your branch through an interactive rebase, but I doubt this is the case. However, if it is , then do the following:

```
git format-patch -1 commit_in_which_you_modified_the_file
```

Suppose your branch has 2 commits, do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This will take you to a menu that looks like

```
pick commit_hash_of_1st_commit ...
pick commit_hash_of_2st_commit ...
```

Suppose the files you do not want to add are part of the 1st commit , you will 'drop' the first commit by deleting the line, or commenting it out:

```
# pick commit_hash_of_1st_commit ...
pick commit_hash_of_2st_commit ...
```

Escape from your editor, and you should have what you need on your branch. Also, remember, you have a patch, which you can later`apply`.

```
Pros:
    - logically simple
    - idiomatically Git


Cons:
    - interactive rebase can be an overwhelming task the first time.
```

**Method 2.** Pick out the specific commits from your branch that modify the files you do not want to commit. Through an interactive rebase, `edit` these commits.

Suppose your branch has 2 commits, do

```
    git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This will take you to a menu that looks like

```
    pick commit_hash_of_1st_commit ...
    pick commit_hash_of_2st_commit ...
```

Suppose the files you do not want to add are part of the 1st commit, you will `edit` the first commit:

```
edit commit_hash_of_1st_commit ...
pick commit_hash_of_2st_commit ...
```

At this point, escape from your editor. When you do it, Git will apply the first commit, but let you `edit` it after the fact.

Do:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

This will uncommit, and unstage, the changes that were part of the first commit. This gives you a clean slate to start over again *in the context of that one commit*.

Then:

- `git add` only those changes you want
- `git commit`
- `git add` the rest of the changes:

  - `git diff > mypatch.patch`

Pros:

- This is the correct way to do it.

Cons:

- Interactive rebase can be an overwhelming exercise the first 
  time.

**Method 3.** Add an ultimate commit to your branch in which you can undo all of the changes you made to the files. You can refer to the change set of this ultimate commit to reconstruct the changes you made to the files you wanted to exclude later.

```
Pros:

    - easy to do (assuming there aren't too many changes)

Cons:

    - corrupts VC history
    - is not idiomatic usage of Git
```

**Method 4.** If your branch has one commit, `git reset HEAD~1`, and recommit only the things you want.

```
Pros:
    - it is straightforward, basically a modification of one of the previous methods
```

**Method 5.** Create a new branch and start over again. I don't think it should come to this, although , given the nature of your branch, it might not be difficult, and possible is the practical method.