# Exclude files from rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I want to exclude some files while rebase or merge.

I tried several approaches like adding them in `.gitattributes`:

```
file1.php merge=ours
file2.php merge=ours
```

Using `skip-worktree`, `.git/hooks/pre-rebase` and several others. But I am not able to achieve the desired behavior.

When I rebase dev from master I don't want file1.php and file2.php from master and when I rebase master from dev I don't want file1.php and file2.php from dev.

I want persistent behavior that is I want this behavior whenever I do the rebase or merge those files should be intact as their own branches.

Note: Using gitattributes, worked only for the first time. Rebasing after then, it brings other branches code. So, I am looking for a persistent solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38044483/7976758 "*The short answer is simple: no.*" https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+exclude+files+merge

Answer (score 1):

In general, this isn't possible.  Git's merge algorithm, which is used for both rebases and merges, looks at three different points, the two heads involved, and a third commit, called the *merge base*, which is usually the most common ancestor.  (The values used for these are different for rebases, but the same algorithm applies.)

Git has an optimization such that if the blob is the same in the merge base and one branch, but different in the other, then it completely ignores the merge machinery, including all configured options, and adopts the changed version.  That's because a three-way merge (like Git uses) is supposed to adopt the changes in both sides, and if one side is identical and the other is changed, then Git adopts the change.  That's almost certainly what's happening here, and why this just isn't going to work.

If these files contain some sort of code that should be different, you can write a single file that does the different behaviour based on some configuration option, and then use a script to set the configuration option based on the branch or any other criteria you choose.  If they contain configuration, it's best to split that out into two separate configuration files, one for each environment, which are all in both branches, and use a script to symlink or select the configuration file to use.