# Exclude a file in merge request

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a project in GitLab that consists of 3 branches, each one for a deployment environment: test, staging, production. In each branch, I have a Dockerfile, and its content varies depending on the branch. I need that when I create a merge request, that Dockerfile is excluded so that the Dockerfiles for each branch remain different. Is this possible?

I tried using a .gitattributes file with this content, but it didn't work:

```
Dockerfile merge=ours
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38044483/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+exclude+merge

Answer (score -1):

**If the files do not change over time**, you can pull it off by doing a first *merge* (a real merge) between two branches and then correcting the file back to what is on that branch that you are working on.... after that happens, git will not modify the file for that branch when you merge with the same branch.

So.... suppose you have this:

```
* III Sixth commit in main branch... I also modify hello.txt (main)
* HHH Fifth commit in main branch
* GGG Fourth commit in main branch
| * FFF Third commit in branch2... I change file hello.txt (branch2)
| * EEE Second commit in branch2
| * DDD First commit in branch2
|/
* CCC Third commit
* BBB Second commit
* AAA First commit
```

So, we run

```
git checkout main
git merge --no-commit branch2
```

Regardless of there being conflicts or not, you want `hello.txt` back the way it is in `main` so you do:

```
git restore --source=HEAD -- hello.txt
git commit "merging branch2"
```

With that we get the file back and we finish the commit, now we have this:

```
* JJJ Merging branch2 (HEAD -> main)
|\
* | III Sixth commit in main branch... I also modify hello.txt
* | HHH Fifth commit in main branch
* | GGG Fourth commit in main branch
| * FFF Third commit in branch2... I change file hello.txt (branch2)
| * EEE Second commit in branch2
| * DDD First commit in branch2
|/
* CCC Third commit
* BBB Second commit
* AAA First commit
```

From this moment on, *as long as there are no changes in `hello.txt` in `branch2`*, you can be certain that git will *not* bring any changes into `hello.txt` when merging `branch2` into `main` branch.